# Read JSON data with AngularJS from PHP connecting to SQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, angularjs

I'll briefly explain what I am trying to do.

I have different entries on a mySql database, I want to load them from a PHP page, convert to JSON, and eventually read them back through AngularJS. So far I have manage to do all the steps but the last one. I'll go step by step so that other people can use this as a reference:

**/// GRAB DATA FROM SQL DATABASE WITH PHP**

access_db.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php

    $host = "myhost";
    $user = "myusername";
    $psw = "mypsw";
    $dbname = "mydatabasename";

    //open connection to mysql db
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$psw,$dbname); // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT EntryName as name, EntryType as type, EntryPlatform as platform, EntryStatus as status, EntryDate as submitDate FROM pl_entries";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $rows = array();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
        echo json_encode($rows);
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If I run the php file, i get this:

[{"name":"name1","type":"type1","platform":"platform1","status":"status1","submitDate":"date1"},{"name":"name2","type":"type2","platform":"platform2","status":"status2","submitDate":"date2"},{"name":"name3","type":"type3","platform":"platform3","status":"status3","submitDate":"date3"},{"name":"name4","type":"type4","platform":"platform4","status":"status4","submitDate":"date4"}]

The connection with the database therefore seem to work correctly.

**/// READ THE JSON WITH ANGULARJS**
(the problematic part)

for this of course I need both an HTML page as well as a JS file.

dbService.js

```
var app = angular.module('dbApp', []);

function GetEntries($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/php/access_db.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.entries = data;
    });
}
```

index.html (I removed part of the code to make it more readable)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


        <!-- AngularJS -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/dbService.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="dbApp">  

            <div class="main" ng-controller="GetEntries">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- ENTRIES LIST -->

                    <div id="diary">
                        <div ng-repeat="entry in entries | orderBy: '-date'">
                            <div class="row">

                                    <h1>{{ entry.submitDate | date: 'dd' }}</h1>
                                    <p>{{ entry.submitDate | date: 'MMM'}}, {{ entry.submitDate | date: 'yyyy'}}</p>

                                    <p>{{ entry.type }}</p>
                                    <h1>{{ entry.name }}</h1>
                                    <p>{{ entry.platform }}</p>
                                    <p>{{ entry.status }}</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

The result of this is that nothing shows up on index.html.

EDIT: to be clearer, none of the AngularJS elements appear, which I guess means that it correctly tries to load data, but probably can't correctly parse it.

I believe the project is in the JS file, but at this point I tried so many different things that I am just confused. I hope someone can help me out understanding how to fix this situation, I hope I provided enough details.

Thanks!

Comment: add console.log(data); after $scope.entries = data; and copy paste or tell me what you have in console please

Comment: Try adding `$scope.getEntries();` after the function

Comment: Are you sure you declare the controller correctly? I can't tell since you did not give that piece of code

Comment: At this stage I'm sure I messed up the controller, as you mentioned. That is actually the only code I have on my js file

Comment: @ThomasP1988 for some whatever reason Firebug doesn't want to debug the page and I have no idea why...

Comment: add this  $http.get('/php/access_db.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.entries = data;
    }).
   error(function(data, status) {
      console.log(status);
   });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few possible reasons why you are facing this problem. Try to make sure your controller is working first. Check your console to see it is initiating or not.

I think you are confused between controller and service. I saw you injected GetServices which meant for services not controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('dbApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GetEntries', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
   console.log("Initiating the controller");
   $http.get('/php/access_db.php').success(function(data) {
    $scope.entries = data;
    });
}]);
```

Here is a simple app with `$http.get` usage. I use random API but it should work with your PHP server. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzPrkg8yokh1jXtzrmdR

This is not really a good practice. Try to move the http request to services instead of controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @geckob. For some whatever reason Firebug doesn't want to debug the page and I can't check the console...

Comment: @AlexKalopsia: Weird. I am not familiar with Firefox. I am using Chrome. What do you mean can't check the console?

Comment: ok, I managed to fix the problem. here's the console log:

`Initiating the controller
angular.min.js:102 ReferenceError: $http is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (dbService.js:5)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js:36)
    at x.instance (angular.min.js:76)
    at angular.min.js:59
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at M (angular.min.js:59)
    at g (angular.min.js:51)
    at g (angular.min.js:51)
    at angular.min.js:51
    at angular.min.js:18`

Comment: I am sorry. I missed the `$http` injection. Fixed the code

Comment: no worries. the console output is:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.....com/php/access_db.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://....com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: I added header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  at the beginning of the php file and now I get this:

`Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=entry%20in%20entries%20%7C%20orderBy%3A%20'-date'&p1=string%3At&p2=t
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js:6:417
    at XMLHttpRequest.H.onload (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js:86:462)`

Can it be that I should remove the HTML tags from the php file?

Comment: Great. That is a CORS problem. Nice you fixed it. 

Maybe. But your php file should not contain any html tag I believe. It should return a JSON data.

Comment: @AlexKalopsia: If you want to debug the app, you can also read it from files instead of request it from the server.

Comment: YES!!! It works now! I also removed the <!DOCTYPE html><html><body> at the beginning and at the end of the php page and now it works! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP. I usually do it using Express server. Glad it works for you! Please accept as answer then :)